# Array<T> extension to filter and unwrap optionals

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, dictionary, filter

I'm trying to filter out an array of optionals and unwrap them.
So I wrote the following extension to Array struct but I'm getting the error: 'T' is not a subtype of 'UInt8'

Any idea if this is possible with swift ?

```
extension Array {
    func filterOptionals() -> [T] {
        return filter({$0 != nil }).map({$0!})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array can contain elements of any type, which is not necessarily `'Optional<T>'`. It is not currently possible, and might never be, to write specialised extensions of generic types. We must use global functions instead:

```
func filterOptionals<T>(array: [T?]) -> [T] {
    return array.filter {$0 != nil } .map {$0!}
}
```

Comment: I have the same function as a global function but i wanted the extra convenience and natural functional chaining to be able to do: object.getMixedArray.filterOptionals().doSomething()

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible. You could use a postfix operator instead, or wrap your array into another struct ArrayOfOptionals<T>.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Here is how:

```
extension Array {
    func catOptionals<A>() -> [A] where Element == A? {
        return self.flatMap{ $0 }
    }
}
```